# Thread hanging when calling LinkedList.add

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

So I'm writing two ServerSockets. One that listens for HTTP requests on port 8085 and saves the byte input into a static LinkedList, and a second that listens on port 8086 and returns all the results in the static LinkedList.

The issue is that when saving the data from ServerSocket:8085 to the LinkedList, the thread hangs and I'm not sure why.

This is the main Listener class:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.*;

public class Listener {

    public static LinkedList<byte[]> Calls = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread callback = new Thread(new ThreadListener());
        callback.start();

        while (true) {
            try (var listener = new ServerSocket(8086)) {
                System.out.println("Listening on 8086...");
                try (var client = listener.accept()) {
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    response.append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
                    Iterator<byte[]> iterator = Calls.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        response.append(new String(iterator.next(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")) + "\r\n");
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                    client.getOutputStream().write(response.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    client.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

This is the ThreadListener class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.Date;

public class ThreadListener implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try (var listener = new ServerSocket(8085)) {
                System.out.println("Listening on 8085...");
                try (var socket = listener.accept()) {
                    if (!socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().equals("127.0.0.1")) {
                        System.out.println("Not localhost");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Its us!");
                    }
                    Listener.Calls.add(socket.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
                    System.out.println("Result collected");
                    Date today = new Date();
                    String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + today;
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    socket.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for my test, I tried calling 127.0.0.1:8085, and I get an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, and all I have in the console is the following:

```
Listening on 8085...
Listening on 8086...
Its us!

Process finished with exit code -1 (I killed the app after 2 mins)
```

The fact that the "Its us!" message got printed, but the "Results collected!" right after the LinkedList.add didn't is what leads me to assume the LinkedList.add is the one hanging the thread.

Regards

EDIT: No one is calling to 8085 (or 8086), I'm doing it manually on my browser. I solved the Syncronization issue by creating a method to call instead of calling the LinkedList.add directly:

```
    public static synchronized void addElementsToList(byte[] bytes) {
        Calls.add(bytes);
    }
```

This does work, but calling the 8085 socket gives the connection reset every time.

Comment: Besides the synchronization issue, who is writing to the 8085 server? Does the application that writes there close the stream when it finishes writing to it? If it's a program, show its code as well. If not, explain how it's done. Please [edit] the question to add the information, don't use the comments, except to tell us you updated.

Comment: Updated @RealSkeptic

Comment: Your synchronized method is wrong. Don't use synchronized static methods. They synchronize on the class object, and may cause issues if you ever use `wait` and `notify`. Also, synchronization means nothing if you only synchronize while writing, but ignore the synchronization while reading. Your iterator changes `Calls` while it runs. That's very bad. You should use a blocking queue instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test mechanism of using a browser to create the request is probably also not helping here, as the `InputStream.readAllBytes()`

> blocks until all remaining bytes have been read and end of stream is detected, or an exception is thrown. This method does not close the input stream.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--). Specifically, the browser is keeping the connection open, because it's expecting some response. Your server is trying to read everything from the connection *until the connection is closed*. Catch 22 (aka deadlock).

Try making the connection to `localhost:8085` using `telnet` *and closing the connection from the client end*.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8085

^D
```

where `^D` is literally the [CTRL] and [D] keys (eg: logout)

Comment: Correct, switching to `socket.getInputStream().readNBytes(socket.getInputStream().available())` fixed the issue.

Comment: Awesome. I wonder if there's a badge for multiple distinct answers on the same question getting upvotes ;-)

Comment: @TomasBreuer That method (using `available`) is **wrong**. It means you only read the bytes that were buffered locally, but if you send a long communication, bigger than your local buffer, `available()` will not reflect the complete text. Please read the documentation for `available()` carefully.

Answer (score 1):

A `LinkedList` is not `synchornized`, [as highlighted in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

You can either handle synchronisation manually, use a synchronised list, or a concurrent list. Probably some other methods too, but for now, just keep it simple.

```
public static LinkedList<byte[]> Calls = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());

// or

public static LinkedList<byte[]> Calls = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Adding the syncronized method worked, I'm still struggling with the connection reset issue now.